# Make all items in a QTreeWidget editable

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

Is it possible to make all items in a QTreeWidget editable on user double-click?

[image]

I have already set the only editing-related property I found - `editTriggers` - to `DoubleClicked|EditKeyPressed`, but the items are still not editable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from https://forum.qt.io/topic/20980/solved-can-qtreewidget-really-be-edited. Apparently each item needs to have its editable flag set.

To do it, I iterated over all of the items and set the editable flag:

```
QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(ui->treeWidget);
while (*it) {
    (*it)->setFlags((*it)->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    ++it;
}
```

It works after that!